# Oracle Historical Session Information

Tags: oracle-10g

I want to know the view or query which provides the total number of active and non-active session for a specific snapshot. Currently I am using the below query.

```
SELECT INSTANCE_NUMBER, count(*)*10 "DB Sessions"
FROM DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY
where snap_id = '78131'
GROUP BY INSTANCE_NUMBER;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that DBA_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY only stores details of active sessions. It's in the name.

Comment: I need the total number of sessions, include active and non-active sessions.

Comment: If you just want the count then you should (by using a script and a table) sample gv$license as-needed. e.g. "select systimestamp, sessions_current,sessions_highwater from gv$license". Store the output in a table and then use it for whatever purpose. By default Oracle does not track this information in any of HIST tables.

Comment: Can i get the info from gv$license snapshot wise. As for the information i am able to get the total number of session by generating AWR report for the period.

Answer (score 3):

Is not nice, is not elegant, but still it works.
Hope this helps to any lost DB Adventurer in a desperate crusade for a sessions historical report.

```
COL METRIC_NAME FOR A40
COL BEGIN_TIME FOR A20
COL END_TIME FOR A20
COL METRIC_UNIT FOR A20
set lin 330 pages 5000

SELECT 
AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID,      AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID,     AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER,      
AVG_SES_COUNT.BEGIN_TIME,   AVG_SES_COUNT.END_TIME, 
--AVG_SES_COUNT.METRIC_NAME,        
AVG_SES_COUNT.AVERAGE AVG_TOTAL_SESSIONS,       AVG_SES_COUNT.MAXVAL MAX_TOTAL_SESSIONS,
-----
AVG_ACT_SES.AVERAGE                AVG_ACTIVE_SESSIONS,     AVG_ACT_SES.MAXVAL            MAX_ACTIVE_SESSIONS,
-----
AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS.AVERAGE        AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS,     AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS.MAXVAL    MAX_SERIAL_SESSIONS,
-----
AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS.AVERAGE      AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS,   AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS.MAXVAL  MAX_PARALLEL_SESSIONS,
-----
AVG_PQ_SESSIONS.AVERAGE      AVG_PQ_SESSIONS,   AVG_PQ_SESSIONS.MAXVAL  MAX_PQ_SESSIONS,
-----
AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS.AVERAGE      AVG_PQ_SLAVE_SESSIONS,     AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS.MAXVAL  MAX_PQ_SLAVE_SESSIONS
FROM 
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2143 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID ) AVG_SES_COUNT,
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2147 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID ) AVG_ACT_SES,
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2148 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID ) AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS,
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2148 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID )  AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS,
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2137 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID )  AVG_PQ_SESSIONS,
(select  SNAP_ID,       DBID,       INSTANCE_NUMBER,        BEGIN_TIME,         END_TIME,       METRIC_NAME,        AVERAGE,        MAXVAL,         METRIC_UNIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where  METRIC_ID=2138 
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID )  AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS
WHERE
    AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID           = AVG_ACT_SES.SNAP_ID       (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID              = AVG_ACT_SES.DBID          (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER   = AVG_ACT_SES.INSTANCE_NUMBER (+)
--
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID           = AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS.SNAP_ID       (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID              = AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS.DBID          (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER   = AVG_SERIAL_SESSIONS.INSTANCE_NUMBER (+)
--
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID           = AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS.SNAP_ID         (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID              = AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS.DBID            (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER   = AVG_PARALLEL_SESSIONS.INSTANCE_NUMBER (+) 
--
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID           = AVG_PQ_SESSIONS.SNAP_ID       (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID              = AVG_PQ_SESSIONS.DBID          (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER   = AVG_PQ_SESSIONS.INSTANCE_NUMBER (+)       
--
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.SNAP_ID           = AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS.SNAP_ID       (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.DBID              = AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS.DBID          (+)
AND AVG_SES_COUNT.INSTANCE_NUMBER   = AVG_PQ_SLV_SESSIONS.INSTANCE_NUMBER (+)           
order by INSTANCE_NUMBER,SNAP_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

`DBA_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` is only from active sessions, but you can query `dba_hist_sysmetric_summary` as I explain in this article: [Oracle Historical Session Information](http://bbdd-error.blogspot.com.es/2017/10/oracle-historical-session-information.html)

Comment: Could you please include the important bits here?